# Como posso otimizar uma consulta em Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Possuo várias tabelas vinculadas e quando eu faço uma consulta ele retorna todas as `query`:

**Model:**

```
class Apontamento extends Model
{

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(\App\User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
  }

  public function cliente()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Cliente::class, 'id', 'cliente_id');
  }
  public function servico()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Servico::class, 'id', 'servico_id');
  }
  public function participante()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\RelacaoAp::class);
  }
  public function kanban()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Kanban::class, 'id', 'kanban_id');
   
  }
  public function descricaoAp()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Descricao_ap::class, 'apontamentodesc_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

Eloquent que uso bem pouco, faço pouca alterações "quase nunca": `User`, `Servico`, `Cliente`, o que eu poderia para fazer para não ficar carregando toda hora, já tentei com `Cache::remember();` mas nada!

**Controller:**

```
 public function index(Request $request)
  {
    $getCliente = $request->cliente;
    $getAtividade = $request->atividade;
    $getResponsavel = $request->responsavel;
    $getDataF = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $request->dataF)));

    $qbuilder = new Apontamento();

    if ($qbuilder) {
      if (!empty($getCliente)) {
        $qbuilder = Apontamento::whereHas('cliente', function ($query) use ($getCliente) {
          $query->where('razao', 'LIKE', '%' . $getCliente . '%');
        });
      }
      if (!empty($getAtividade)) {
        $qbuilder = Apontamento::where('atividade', 'LIKE', '%' . $getAtividade . '%');
      }
      if (!empty($getResponsavel)) {
        $qbuilder = Apontamento::whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($getResponsavel) {
          $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $getResponsavel . '%');
        });
      }
      if (!empty($getDataF)) {
        $qbuilder = Apontamento::whereHas('descricaoAp', function ($query) use ($getDataF) {
          $query->whereRaw('DATE(apontamentoData) = ?', [$getDataF]);
        });
      }
    }

    $apontamentos = $qbuilder->orderBy('dataApontamento', 'DESC')->paginate(10);


    $clientes = Cliente::orderBy('CodCliente', 'asc')->get();
    $servicos = Servico::all();
    $partici = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
      $query->where("name", "equipe")->orWhere("name", "admin");
    })->get();

    return view(
      'webadmin.apontamento.listar',
      compact('clientes', 'servicos', 'apontamentos', 'partici', 'totalHrs')
    );
  }
```

Como posso otimizar, para evitar a repetição desse trecho no **Controller**, devo criar na **model** ou em qual pasta?

Comment: Eu realmente não entendi sua pergunta e seu problema.

Comment: @JedsonMelo, desculpa se eu não fui muito claro, estou sofrendo com lentidão e repetição de código

Comment: `$qbuilder = new Apontamento();` ai depois se faz isso de novo com uma pesquisa e se for satisfeito pelos `if` vai ser feito de novo. Se está usando completamente errado porque você está repetendido em todos os momentos a mesma classe. Lentidão é um caso a parte quantos registros você retorna?